# How to create an interactive copula plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, copula

I have the data and I want to create copula plot. but the plot is not interactive. How do I complete the code so that it can provide interactive copula plot results like the example image that I included: [example plot](https://images.app.goo.gl/2dzdph1dwQ3Y9KVw9)

```
mycop20 <- frankCopula(param = 2.294263, dim = 2)
my_dist20 <- mvdc(frankCopula(param = 2.294263, dim = 2),
                  margins = c("LO","LO"),
                  paramMargins = list(
                    list(mu = fk20_1$mu, sigma = fk20_1$sigma), 
                    list(mu = fk20_2$mu, sigma = fk20_2$sigma)))

uu=rCopula(2000,mycop20)
pdf_cop=dCopula(uu,mycop20)
cdf_cop=pCopula(uu,mycop20)

# Plot Fungsi Kepadatan Frank Copula
library(scatterplot3d)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
scatterplot3d(uu[,1],uu[,2], pdf_cop, color="red", main="Density", xlab = "u1", ylab="u2", zlab="dCopula",pch=".")
persp(mycop20, dCopula, main = "Density")
contour(mycop20, dCopula, main = "Contour plot")
```

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/copula/html/contourplot2-methods.html